# Space between two column minipages

Tags: spacing, minipage

I'm using the OpenFonts version in this repository, which is a resume template for CS majors: https://github.com/deedydas/Deedy-Resume

In the resume template, there are two column minipages created, with each column meant to have several subsections, such as Education, Links, Coursework in the first column and Experience, Research, Awards, Societies in the next column.

I want to increase the space between the two columns and I tried the solutions to several questions here to set the space between two minipages, but none of them worked. How do I set the space between the minipages here? I fiddled around with the code a lot, and I've seen several variations happen, including the overflow issue the repo owner mentions in the README.

EDIT: Here's a minimal .xtx file. `deedy-resume-openfont.cls` is the class file.

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}

\begin{document}

\lastupdated

\namesection{Debarghya}{Das}{ \urlstyle{same}\url{http://debarghyadas.com} \\
\href{mailto:dd367@cornell.edu}{dd367@cornell.edu} | 607.379.5733
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     COLUMN ONE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth} 

% Sections like Education, Links, Coursework over here


\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}

%Sections like Experience, Research, Awards, Societies over here

\end{minipage}
\end{document}  \documentclass[]{article}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem and shows your failed attempt. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill Edited the question. Please let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: is that class really needed to demonstrate the problem, it seems it is just minipages, an example using `article` class would be much better. In any case your two minipages add up to .99\textwidth and you have a word space and \hfill glue between them, even if the hfill stretches to 0pt the word space will probably make you overfull.  If you want to increase the space you need to make th eminipages narrower so reduce .33\textwidth or .66\textwidth depending on the effect you want

Comment: Just noticed you have a blank line (paragraph break) between the minipages so presumably they come one above the other? you need to remove that as well, unless the class is doing something strange with `\par`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for the typo - yes, there is no blank line after the `\hfill` and the next minipage's begin. I accidentally added that while commenting `COLUMN TWO` over there.